Cannot join my own gameserver via my external IP
In short, when I launch a game server on Windows, I can only join it via the local IP address but not via my public IP.
The server and the client are on the same machine, same interface. The server is run directly on the host, no Virtual Box.
Here is my setup:
I have a router that forwards a 3457 UDP port to 192.168.0.102.
192.168.0.102 is the local IP of my host computer.
I launch a gameserver on this 192.168.0.102 interface and these commands show the following:
> netstat -ano | findstr 3457
  UDP    192.168.0.102:3457     *:*                                    34192

Let's assume 50.100.30.68 is my public IP.
> ncat -vnzu 50.100.30.68 3457
Ncat: Version 7.95 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 50.100.30.68:3457.
Ncat: UDP packet sent successfully
Ncat: 1 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 2.18 seconds.

nmap -sU -v -p 3457 50.100.30.68

PORT     STATE         SERVICE
3457/udp open|filtered prsvp

I can join my server directly by entering the local IP address 192.168.0.102 but not with my public IP address 50.100.30.68.
There is one point to add.
I tried to run this server on a Virtual Box on the same host. The VM on the virtual box uses host network with the 192.168.0.103 IP address. Port forwarding is also configured for this address on the router.
When I run a sever on the 192.168.0.103 interface on the Virtual Box VM, I can join it via my public IP from the 192.168.0.102 host machine (Server VM and client are on the same physical machine but on different interfaces).
I'm using a simple NAT (PC + router) and I have a dedicated IP from my ISP.
Could you explain what going on there and how to debug this case?
P.S. I'm not sure if the issue is related to some sort of a traffic collision described on these forums:
https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/1878676-cant-connect-to-my-own-server-from-external-ip
https://bukkit.org/threads/i-cant-connect-to-my-own-server.201191/

Are you paying the ISP for a static IP, or is this just the IP address assigned to you by the ISP? If the latter, this is based on how big ISP networks work.

Just to confirm. You are NOT behind a CGNAT? I ask because lots of people don’t know how to determine if that’s the case and it’s honestly the number one reason port forwarding doesn’t work.

I added the details to my post. I'm using a simple NAT and have a dedicated IP. Also, pay attention that I can join my external IP if I run a server via virtual box.

Could be due to something called "NAT hairpinning" aka "NAT loopback" aka "NAT reflection". A technique meant to allow the use of a public IP for a service that is in your local network. Your router may not support this or support may be disabled.

Since I can join my external IP if I run a server on Virtual Box host network, "NAT hairpinning" seems to work. But why it does not work without virtual box if the client-server interface is the same.

@t7e Some routers can do hairpin, but ONLY if the internal source/destination are different mac-addresses. Seems to depend on how the routing/NAT engine is designed inside the routers firmware. I've run into the same issue. Had to stick a 2nd NIC in the server just to have a different interface to act as the client. Luckily for me the client and server application both allowed binding them to specifc ip-addresses. Please note that you don't have to run the server in a VM. Running the client in one would achieve the same effect and is (maybe) less hassle.

If you have a computer or laptop with WiFi, you can use your phone to make a hotspot, connect wifi to that hotspot and you can then test the connection. To join your server to actually play, just use the internal ip address.

NAT hairpinning, most likely. You send out a packet to the internet, its immediately sent back to the router, the router does not expect it and ignores it. Unless the router can be instructed to know that this packet should be routed internally, you generally need to create a workaround.

As it turned out, clients can't join my public server via external IP too.
Nat negotiation error. I have no idea where to look at.
